# Apache CXF CachedOutputStream NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, web-services

Help!

I'm getting this error when trying to connect using JAX-WS webservice call:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/io/CachedOutputStream

Any idea on what's happening?

Update: I added all these jar files

- cxf.jar
- commons-logging.jar
- geronimo-activation.jar (Or the Sun equivalent) [6]
- geronimo-annotation.jar (Or the Sun equivalent) [6]
- geronimo-javamail.jar (Or the Sun equivalent) [6]
  (MAY be able to remove javamail if you don't use any MTOM/SAAJ type things)
- geronimo-stax-api.jar (Or the Sun equivalent) [6]
- neethi.jar
- jaxb-api.jar  [6]
- jaxb-impl.jar (this is a [6] for normal runtime, but is required for 
               tooling and the dynamic clients)
- XmlSchema.jar
- woodstox-core-asl.jar  [6] or another StAX implementation
- stax2-api-3.0.1.jar [6] for woodstox above
- wsdl4j.jar

**Another Update:**

Now I get the following error message:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.customEditorConfigurer' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/lib/cxf-2.3.3.jar!/META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.fixml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrar[]' for property 'propertyEditorRegistrars'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.spring.SoapVersionRegistrar] to required type [org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrar] for property 'propertyEditorRegistrars[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have all of CXF in your classpath. Did you read the WHICH_JARS file? How did you set up your classpath.

Note that there's no such thing as 'cxf.jar'. It's always 'cxf-VERSION.jar', and the same applies to other redistributed jars. Compare WHICH_JARS to the contents of the lib dir.